# Delete Unresponsive channels - java

Tags: java, network-programming, nonblocking

My question is how to delete from the selector, the hosts that are not responding in a given time.

Suppose that, i have 1 channel registered in selector for OP_CONNECT. The channel is in nonblocking mode. The host that i added i know that its not responding, so my program cannot connect, and the select() method of the selector will always return 0. Now, How i can use the select(timeout) and delete the not responding hosts?

The output of ping of host:

```
25 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 24000ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just close the channel(s) concerned. That will automatically cancel all their `SelectionKeys` and remove them from the purview of the `Selector(s)` concerned.

However I personally can't see the point of NIO or non-blocking mode for clients.

Comment: Thanks. NIO is handful for Web Crawlers with small resources :)

Comment: If i add a channel now, and is unresponsive, and the selector's select() waits for 4000 milis for timeout. And in the 3000th milisecond another channel is added to selector. But the second channel wants 2000 miliseconds to respond because have high overhead. If the select() will return 0 i will close all the channels as you suggested. Is this solution will delete the second channel too?? If yes, then its not the right solution

Comment: @GiorgosFandomas None of that can happen. You can't register another channel without waking up the selector. In any case, channel closures and key cancellations don't take effect until the following `select()`.